# Mask numpy array in columns based on row index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask

I have a numpy array with a shape of (4, 5, 5). I want to create a mask and apply it on all of  the values in specific columns based on the row index number.

for example

```
[[[7 3 5 5 0]  
  [0 8 5 2 2]  
  [0 0 8 7 4]  
  [4 0 6 0 4]  
  [8 3 8 6 5]] 

 [[4 6 3 2 7]  
  [0 2 0 0 5]  
  [7 7 4 8 8]  
  [4 1 2 7 8]  
  [8 8 3 2 8]] 

 [[8 3 0 4 5]  
  [8 1 4 6 1]  
  [0 6 7 7 7]  
  [0 8 2 6 5]  
  [3 2 8 8 1]] 

 [[6 5 1 4 0]  
  [4 7 4 7 0]  
  [8 3 8 7 4]  
  [5 8 6 2 0]  
  [0 7 2 6 0]]]
```

I want to apply a mask on all of the elements in all four columns in the row with an `index` value of `3`.

The desired output would look like this

```
[[[False, False, False, False, False]  
  [False, False, False, False, False]  
  [False, False, False, False, False]  
  [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]  
  [False, False, False, False, False]] 

 [[False, False, False, False, False]  
  [False, False, False, False, False]  
  [False, False, False, False, False]  
  [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]  
  [False, False, False, False, False]] 

 [[False, False, False, False, False]  
  [False, False, False, False, False]  
  [False, False, False, False, False]  
  [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]  
  [False, False, False, False, False]] 

 [[False, False, False, False, False]  
  [False, False, False, False, False]  
  [False, False, False, False, False]  
  [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True]  
  [False, False, False, False, False]]]
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want.  Can you show what the desired output is after the mask is applied?

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation on [numpy array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html) as there might be a better way to achieve the end goal.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

Assuming `A` is the original array with the data in that you want to apply the mask to.

```
mask = np.full(A.shape, False)
mask[:, 3, :] = True
```

UPDATE:

From your comments I see that your ultimate goal is to do some calculations on the selected values.  You don't need to generate a mask for this.  Just use numpy indexing:

```
mean = np.mean(A[:, 3, :])
```

Comment: yes that's exactly what I was looking for thank you!

Comment: See my comment above.  Many basic questions like this can be answered by reading the documentation.  Only post on stackoverflow when you have done that and are still stuck.